# How to limit user to input a float with one decimal point in C

Tags: c, input, decimal, limit, point

Program to limit the user's input to one decimal point in C.

For example:

Enter grade: 5 //Acceptable
Enter grade: 8.5 //Acceptable
Enter grade: 6.4**67** //Not acceptable, Re-enter grade

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{       
    double grade[8];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {           
        printf("Insert grade: ");
        scanf("%f", &grade[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `getline` and parse the string yourself?

Comment: `atof` function will probably be useful

Answer (score 1):

You will have to input the data as string, then check it only has one decimal place.

It is not possible to input a floating-point value and then check for decimal places; since the floating point values are stored internally with *binary places* and hold an approximation of the value that was input, in most cases.

The input code could look like:

```
char temp[20];
if ( 1 != scanf("%19s", temp) )
     return EXIT_FAILURE;

// code to check for decimal place goes here - I'm purposefully not 
// showing it as this looks like homework!

// once we have checked that the input is correct, then convert to double
grade[i] = strtod(temp, NULL);
```

Comment: It might be possible instead to do `scanf`, then `strtod`, then `sprintf` with a 1d.p. format string, then `strcmp` with the original input ... however I think that would be less reliable, there might be various corner cases where it doesn't work

Comment: Agree about corner cases.  e.g.: `float` like 123456789012345.0`, would not compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf(), scanf()
#include <math.h> // floor()

main()
{

    double grade[8];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {

            do
            {

                printf("Insert grade: ");
                scanf("%lf", &grade[i]);

                grade[i] *= 10;

                if (grade[i] != floor(grade[i])) // Prints error message, if user types more than one decimal point
                {
                    printf("Grade must have one decimal point.\nPlease re-enter grade.\n");
                }

            }while (grade[i] != floor(grade[i])); // Checks decimal point

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` to read the line into a buffer and then test that buffer.

```
char buf[99];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

// parse the line as a float - look for problems
char *endptr;
float f = strtof(buf, &endptr);
if (buf == endptr || *endptr != '\n') Fail_NonFloatInput();

// look for .
char *dot = strchr(buf, '.');
if (dot && isdigit(dot[1]) && isdigit(dot[2])) Fail_TooMuchPrecisison();
}
```

Alternatively code could try:

```
long long i;
int f;
if (2 != scanf("%lld.%1d", &i, &f)) Bad_Input();
float fl = i + f/10.0;
```

But that fails `float` input like `123456789012345678901234567890.0`.
As [@Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494409/2410359) says, read as text first.

Answer (score -2):

You can use printf format specifiers to specificy the number of positions you are interested.

A format specifier follows this prototype: [see compatibility note below]

```
   %[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

Example from the cplusplus.com

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("floats: %4.2f %+.0e %E \n", 3.1416, 3.1416, 3.1416);
    return 0
 }
```

Output

floats: 3.14 +3e+000 3.141600E+000

More examples here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: OP is trying to use `scanf()`, not `printf()` whose specifiers work differently.